# DCEF3 on C++ Builder, how to get ICefCookieManager

Tags: c++, c++builder, tchromium

I compiled DCEF3 in Rad Studio XE for C++. It works perfectly, but I don't know how to work with cookies. I read in delphi that I have to  create variable with type ICefCookieManager, but how can I get that class in C++ Builder? Thanks for help.